# how to convert empty strings into "none" (python 3 using thonny)

Tags: python

im trying to write a program that opens and reads a file and convert numbers in the file to ints. However there are empty strings in the file and i just cant figure how to convert empty strings into "none". Im doing this so that i can bypass the "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10" when i try to convert them into integers later.

using Python 3 on Thonny, new to programming

```
def get_student(studentfile):

with open(studentfile, 'r') as students: #opens file as students
        for aline in students:  

            values = aline.split(",") #breaks up line into strings

            student_names, student_marks = values[:1], values[1:13] #  assigning variables to stings

            for digits in student_marks: ###THIS IS WHERE I HIT A WALL
                if [digits] is None:    ### i tried to turn empty     strings into NONE 
                    [digits] = "None"
                else:
                    return [digits]

            student_marks = list(map(int, student_marks[1:])) #converts number strings into integer

            print( student_names , end="") # combine into a list
            print( [student_marks]) 
            info = students.read()
            students.close
            print( info ) #print list
```

Comment: `[digits]` will always be a list, and a list *never* `is None`.

Comment: Oh okay, im really new to this, but how do i change it to individual string then?

Comment: You could *not* put it in a list; what did you think the square brackets were doing?

Answer (score -1):

Why do you want to make it into `None`? Just Ignore it or you can also split it with new line first and split with comma after, I think that way you will not have an empty string.